# INVOICE number not queue properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, invoice

[Invoice Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJQHt.png)

I'm new to javascript/jquery can you help me with this. I have a POS transaction and when i enter 11 orders it queue properly and correct. from 2015101000000 to 2015101000010 invoice number but when i enter another order here is the bug it did not continue to queue it repeats from 2015101000001. but the correct is 2015101000011. Here is the code.

```
io.on('listOrders', function(pr1) {
    tmc = "";
    if (pr1.length === 0) {
        $("#ordersListContentContainer").html("<span>No Data to Display</span>")
        $("#ordersListStatusCountMin, #ordersListStatusCountMax, #ordersListStatusCountCap").text(0)
    }
    else {
        var tdn = 1;

            for (var i=0; i<pr1.length; i++) {

            var tdc = new Date(pr1[i].dateAdded);
            var tdm = fp.pageDate.getDateFrag(tdc).monthname("2");
            var tdt = fp.pageDate.getDateFrag(tdc).time();
            var tdd = tdm + " " + tdc.getDate() + ", " + tdc.getFullYear() + "&nbsp; | &nbsp;" + tdt;
            var tdp = 1;
            var taa = (pr1[i].orderInvoiceHold);
            var tbb = (parseFloat(pr1[i].transactionAmount).toFixed(2) == "NaN" ? "0.00" : parseFloat(pr1[i].transactionAmount).toFixed(2));
            var tcc = (parseFloat(pr1[i].transactionTotal).toFixed(2) == "NaN" ? "0.00" : parseFloat(pr1[i].transactionTotal).toFixed(2));
            var tbl = (pr1[i].tableID === 0 ? "Take Out" : "Table "+pr1[i].tableID);
            tmc += "<span class='ordersListContentContainerItem' data-num="+(i+1)+" data-pgn="+tdn+" data-ictg='"+pr1[i].itemCategoryLabel+"' data-oorc="+pr1[i].orderCodeHold+" data-horc="+pr1[i].orderCodeHold+" data-oqty="+pr1[i].orderQuantity+" data-oprc="+pr1[i].orderTotalPrice+" data-mods='"+pr1[i].deliMods+"'  data-disc='"+pr1[i].deliDiscounts+"' data-amnt='"+pr1[i].deliCharges+"' data-otra="+pr1[i].transactionAmount+" data-stff="+pr1[i].paymentStaff+" data-cust="+pr1[i].paymentCustomer+"> \
            <span class='listItem l1'>"+tdd+"</span> \
            <span class='listItem l2'>"+taa+"</span> \
            <span class='listItem l3'>"+pr1[i].orderTransaction+"</span> \
            <span class='listItem l4'>"+tbl+"</span> \
            <span class='listItem l5'>"+pr1[i].orderStatus+"</span> \
            <span class='listItem l6'>"+tbb+"</span> \
            <span class='listItem l7'></span> \
            <span class='listItem l8'>"+tcc+"</span> \
            </span>"
            if (tdp % parseInt($("#ordersSubOptsSelect").val()) === 0) {
                tdn += 1;
            }
        }       
        $("#ordersListContentContainer").html(tmc);
        $(".ordersListContentContainerItem").children("span").last().text(function() {
            var aa = 0
            $(".ordersListContentContainerItem").each(function() {
                aa += $(this).data("oprc")*1;
            });
        });
        $(".ordersListContentContainerItem").hide();
        $(".ordersListContentContainerItem[data-pgn='1']").show();
        $("#ordersListStatusCountMin").html($("#ordersListContentContainer").children(".ordersListContentContainerItem:visible").first().data("num"));
        $("#ordersListStatusCountCap").html($("#ordersListContentContainer").children(".ordersListContentContainerItem").length);
        $("#ordersListStatusCountMax").html($("#ordersListContentContainer").children(".ordersListContentContainerItem:visible").last().data("num"));

        var os = function(a) {
            var aa = "<div class='orderSummaryLabelContainer'> \
            <span class='orderSummaryLabel1'>Item</span> \
            <span class='orderSummaryLabel2'>Quantity</span> \
            <span class='orderSummaryLabel3'>Price</span> \
            </div><br><br>";
            var ab = "";
            var aba = 0;
            var abb = 0;
            var abc = 0;
            $(".ordersListContentContainerItem[data-oorc='"+a+"']").each(function() {
                var x = $(this);
                abb = function(a) {
                    var b = "";
                    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
                        if (x.data("oprc") !== 0) {
                            io.emit('orderMods', {
                                hotelID: htld,
                                outletID: otld,
                                vr3: a[i].tid
                            }, true);
                        }
                        b += "<div class='ordersListContentContainerItemMods'> \
                            <span class='orderSummaryModItem' data-num="+x.data("num")+" data-mtid="+a[i].tid+" data-oqty="+a[i].tqt+" data-oprc='"+a[i].tpr+"'></span> \
                            <span class='orderSummaryModQty'>"+a[i].tqt+"</span> \
                            <span class='orderSummaryModPrc'>"+a[i].tpr+"</span> \
                            </div>";
                        abc += a[i].tpr*1;
                    }
                    return b;
                }               
                ab += "<div class='orderSummaryItemContainer' data-oorc='"+x.data("horc")+"'> \
                <span class='orderSummaryItem'>"+$(this).data("ictg")+"</span> \
                <span class='orderSummaryQty'>"+$(this).data("oqty")+"</span> \
                <span class='orderSummaryPrc'>"+parseFloat($(this).data("oprc")).toFixed(2)+"</span>"+abb($(this).data("mods"))+"</div>";
                aba += $(this).data("oprc")*1;
            });

            var ac = "<br><br><div id='orderSummaryPriceContainer'> \
            <span id='orderSummaryPrice1'>Sub Total:</span> \
            <span id='orderSummaryPriceVal1'>"+parseFloat(aba+abc).toFixed(2)+"</span> \
            <span id='orderSummaryPrice2'>Total:</span> \
            <span id='orderSummaryPriceVal2'>0</span> \
            <span id='orderSummaryPrice3'>Grand Total:</span> \
            <span id='orderSummaryPriceVal3'>0</span> \
            <span id='orderSummaryPrice4'>Amount Paid:</span> \
            <span id='orderSummaryPriceVal4'>"+($(".ordersListContentContainerItem[data-oorc='"+a+"']").first().data("otra") === null ? "0.00" : parseFloat($(".ordersListContentContainerItem[data-oorc='"+a+"']").first().data("otra")).toFixed(2))+"</span> \
            </div>";

            return aa+ab+ac;
        };

        $(".ordersListContentContainerItem").on("click", function() {
            var orc = $(this).data("oorc") || $(this).data("horc");
            var onm = 0;
            $("#orderReceiptCost_Total, #orderReceiptCost_TotalValue").hide();
            $("#orderReceiptTableTitleContainer").find("#receiptTransaction").text("Trans #: "+$(this).find(".l3").text());
            $("#orderReceiptTableTitleContainer").find("#receiptInvoice").text("Invoice #: "+$(this).find(".l2").text());
            $("#orderReceiptTableTitleContainer").find("#receiptDate").html($(this).find(".l1").text());
            $("#orderReceiptTableTitleContainer").find("#receiptTable").text($(this).find(".l4").text());
            $("#orderReceiptTableTitleContainer").find("#receiptStaff").text("Staff: "+$(this).data("stff"));
            $("#orderReceiptTableTitleContainer").find("#receiptCustomer").text("Customer: "+$(this).data("cust"));
            fp.pageDialog.DialogDefault_Open("Order Summary - ("+orc+")", os($(this).data("oorc")), 3, function() {
            });
            $("#orderReceiptCost_GrandTotal, #orderReceiptCost_GrandTotalValue").css({"display": "none"});
            $("#orderReceiptCost_GrandTotalValue").text("0.00");
            $(".orderSummaryPriceCharge, .orderSummaryPriceChargeVal, .orderReceiptCost_Charge, .orderReceiptCost_ChargeAmount, .orderSummaryPriceDiscount, .orderSummaryPriceDiscountVal, .orderReceiptCost_Discount, .orderReceiptCost_DiscountValue").remove();
            $("#orderSummaryPriceVal2, #orderSummaryPriceVal3, #orderReceiptCost_TotalValue, #orderReceiptCost_GrandTotalValue").text($("#orderSummaryPriceVal1").text());
            $("#orderReceiptCost_SubTotalValue").text(parseFloat($("#orderSummaryPriceVal1").text()).toFixed(2))
            $("#orderReceiptCost_AmountPaidValue").text(parseFloat($("#orderSummaryPriceVal4").text()).toFixed(2))
            $("#orderReceiptCost_AmountChangeValue").text(parseFloat($("#orderSummaryPriceVal5").text()).toFixed(2))

            if ($(this).data("amnt") !== "") {
                var tma = $(this).data("amnt")+'';
                getOCTotal(tma.split(" ||| "));
            }
            if ($(this).data("disc") !== "") {
                var tmb = $(this).data("disc")+'';
                getODTotal(tmb.split(" ||| "));
            }

            $("#orderReceiptItemContainer").empty();
            $(".ordersListContentContainerItem[data-oorc='"+$(this).data("horc")+"']").each(function() {
                var tgp = "";               
                $("#orderReceiptItemContainer").append("<div class='orderReceiptItem' data-num='"+$(this).data("num")+"' data-oorc='"+$(this).data("horc")+"'><div class='orderReceiptItemGroupMain'><span class='fs'></span><span class='sd'>"+$(this).data("ictg")+"</span><span class='tr'>"+$(this).data("oqty")+"</span><span class='ft'>"+parseFloat($(this).data("oprc")).toFixed(2)+"</span></div><div class='orderReceiptItemGroupMods'></div></div>");
            });

            $(".orderSummaryItemContainer[data-oorc='"+$(this).data("horc")+"']").each(function() {
                onm += ($(this).find(".orderSummaryQty").text()*1);
                $(this).find(".orderSummaryModItem").each(function() {
                    $(".orderReceiptItem[data-num='"+$(this).data("num")+"']").find(".orderReceiptItemGroupMods").show();
                    $(".orderReceiptItem[data-num='"+$(this).data("num")+"']").find(".orderReceiptItemGroupMods").append("<div class='orderReceiptMod'><span class='orderReceiptModDel'><i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i></span><span class='orderReceiptModLabel' data-mtid="+$(this).data("mtid")+">&nbsp;</span><span class='orderReceiptModQuantity'>"+$(this).data("oqty")+"</span><span class='orderReceiptModPrice'>"+$(this).data("oprc")+"</span></div>");
                    io.emit('orderMods', {
                        hotelID: htld,
                        outletID: otld,
                        vr3: $(this).data("mtid")
                    }, false);
                    onm += ($(this).data("oqty")*1);
                });
            });
            $("#orderReceiptCost_NumItemValue").text(onm);
        });
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your order is alphabetical not numeric, which is why it becomes wrong after 10 records.

Make sure everything is cast to integers before applying the sort.

Change line:

> $("#orderReceiptTableTitleContainer").find("#receiptInvoice").text("Invoice #: "+$(this).find(".l2").text());

To be something like:

> $("#orderReceiptTableTitleContainer").find("#receiptInvoice").text("Invoice #: "+parseFloat($(this).find(".l2").text()));

Comment: I have changed the line but still 2015101000001 is the invoice number after 2015101000010. not 2015101000011. do you have any suggestions ? by the way thanks.

Comment: Try cutting it back to the numeric value only to see if it sorts correctly. Cut out the "Invoice #: "+  part.

Comment: even i deleted $("#orderReceiptTableTitleContainer").find("#receiptInvoice").text("Invoice #: "+$(this).find(".l2").text()); this line, invoice number still there.. and not correctly queue .

Comment: start from scratch to confirm the order is working correctly, then progressively move code segments across to see what is breaking the order. Issue isolation strategies.